# Some questions about CSS rules priority

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have the following CSS problem: a website first import a CSS style file named **bootstrap.css** (The BootStrap framework CSS settings), then it is imported another CSS file named **my-custom-style.css** that override some of the **bootstrap.css** settings (so I can create some custom settings leaving unchanged the **bootstrap.css** file)

Now I have the following situation, in the **bootstrap.css** file I have this property that I want to override:

```
.img-thumbnail {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Now I have to override it in my **my-custom-style.css** file in such a way that the **.img-thumbnail** object have no border. So I delcare a

```
.img-thumbnail {

}
```

and I want to say to CSS that the following field (setted in the **bootstrap.css) must not exist in the overrided file (so I have not the border)

```
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: auto;
```

Can I do something like this or have I to override it with a specific value?

I tryied to override it with a specific value but I can override the **background-color** with a new color value (and it work) but when I try to change the **border** value to **0px** it still use the **bootstrap.css** definition

Can you help me to solve this problem? I think that exist an elegant way to simply say: **"don't use the overrided file settings** without explicitly override it with new values

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: border:0 none; don't work? Edited: !important;

Comment: To clarify, it should be either border: 0 or border: none - not both.  It will still work if you use both, but that's because the css is using the last one and the first one is redundant.  This would negatively effect performance on sites with high traffic.  Also you should only ever use !important if you are having to override an inline style that cannot be removed.  That's what !important was created for, not situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the CSS engine will decide which rule to use based in 3 things (listed here in order of importance):

1. `!important` clauses
2. More specific rule
3. Rule order

Now, [**check out this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/By7U3/1/).

---

First, let's talk about the order. We have:

```
div { background:green; }
```

and

```
div { background:gray; }
```

So, which background `CSS` will use? `green` or `gray`? They are both rules with no `!important` clauses, and have the same specification level (both are applied for `div`) only remaining the **order** to decide. In this case `gray` comes last so it will be applied to all `div` elements.

---

Now, the "specificness" of the rule.

```
#div1 { background: red; }
```

This one is a much **more specific** rule than the other rules that apply only to `div` elements. So `#div1` will have a red background even with a `div{ background: gray; }` coming later.

---

And last, but not least `!important`.

These rules are... **important**. They can only be overridden by another `!important` rule that comes later and have the same specific level.

Even if a `!important` rules is declared in a lower level of specification, it won't be overridden. Like in:

```
div { width:50px !important; }
#div2 { border:3px solid blue; width: 100px; }
```

Even coming later and being more specific, `width: 100px;` will not be applied to `#div2`.

---

Now that you know all of this, it's a matter of inspecting the element to see what's going on and then guess "how much power" you'll need to override that rule.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, just override that class in your own css file and add !important at the end